# A twist of fate

Tags: etymology, phrases, idioms

I’ve spent the last few days savouring the phrase “A twist of fate”, either there isn’t much written about, or it is swamped by other people using it.

From what seen on the internet it seems to be medieval in origin, but I imagine it’s roots are deeper still.

What are it’s origins, and is a “twist of lemon” a riff on it?

Comment: Would be helpful to include a reference to the source that leads you to believe that the term is medieval in origin -- this seems to make a big difference and I would not have guessed it to be the case, so would be good to include so answers have that to work from.

Comment: The medieval reference seemed to be a spurious one from some googled link to a web disctiinary with no substance

Answer (score 4):

The earliest usage example of “twist of fate” I could find so far is from  the mid 19th century:

“*[Pierre; Or, The Ambiguities](https://books.google.it/books?id=JXK7HN62EcQC&pg=PA238&dq=%22twist%20of%20fate%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLqcmSpsrfAhUP36QKHY5yCYsQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22twist%20of%20fate%22&f=false)*” by Herman Melville - 1852 - ‎

> And now we behold this hapless youth all eager ***to involve himself in such an inextricable twist of Fate***, that the three dextrous maids themselves could hardly disentangle him, if once he tie the complicating knots about him and Isabel. Ah, thou ...

Comment: _the three dextrous maids themselves_ That's what first occurred to me when reading the question: the Fates, who twist and weave the threads of mortal lives.

Comment: +1 for this ^ comment. In Greek mythology, the Fates literally "twist" your destiny. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moirai#Origins

Comment: Indeed and the Vikings had the Norns weavers of fate, they must have held weaving with great store. However the phrase "Twist of Fate" itself seems to have been first used with the above reference. I thought it might have been Shakesperian

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about two different senses of *twist*. The first refers to some concrete physical item that has been twisted:

> **twist** *n*
>   1. Something twisted or formed by twisting, especially:
>   a. A length of yarn, cord, or thread, especially a strong silk thread used mainly to bind the edges of buttonholes.
>   b. Tobacco leaves processed into the form of a rope or roll.
>   c. A loaf of bread or other bakery product made from pieces of dough twisted together.
>   d. A sliver of citrus peel twisted over or dropped into a beverage for flavoring.

And the second refers to a more abstract convolution, like an unexpected turn in a story or process:

> 8. An unexpected change in a process or a departure from a pattern, often producing a distortion or perversion: *a twist of fate; a story with a quirky twist.*

[The Free Dictionary Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/twist)

The noun form is attested from the mid-14th century, according to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/twist#etymonline_v_18879):

> mid-14c., "flat part of a hinge" (now obsolete), probably from Old English -twist "divided object; fork; rope" (as in mæsttwist "mast rope, stay;" candeltwist "wick"), from Proto-Germanic *twis-, from PIE root *dwo- "two." Original senses suggest "dividing in two" (source also of cognate Old Norse tvistra "to divide, separate," Gothic twis- "in two, asunder," Dutch twist, German zwist "quarrel, discord," though these senses have no equivalent in English), but later ones are of "combining two into one," hence the original sense of the word may be "rope made of two strands."